# upgrading 4000d kit lens to what?

Tags: lens, canon, landscape, wide-angle, kit-lens

I'm thinking about upgrading my lens.

I am currently using a canon 4000d with its kit lens 18mm - 55mm, as I don't have the money at the minute to upgrade both (want to upgrade to a full frame in the future) I think upgrading the lens would be better than upgrading the body.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could upgrade to? I take specifically landscape photos.

I understand that the crop sensor on the 4000d has a crop factor of 1.61 so that means I'm not getting 18mm, I'm getting 28/29mm at its widest.

Would be looking for something that's abit wider and better quality! Any suggestions would be appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bit wider, your main option is the Canon 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 lens that is not compatible with full frame cameras. A full frame lens much wider than 18mm is quite hard to find, as those that are wider are only very slightly wider (17-40L and 16-35L are examples of such).

I have one Canon 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 lens and I'm not entirely satisfied with it. It seems the autofocus is not very accurate. The aperture is not particularly fast, but then again when taking landscape photos it might not matter.

The 10-18mm lens does not have overlapping focal length range with the 18-55mm lens, so strictly speaking it's not an "upgrade".

An upgrade could be Canon 15-85mm lens, not compatible with full frame cameras either. It is slightly wider than 18-55mm, and could be classified as an upgrade. Of course I don't know if 15mm is wide enough for you. The 15-85mm lens is quite expensive, much more than 10-18mm. But then again you get what you pay for.

Comment: May I ask you why the 15-85mm lens would be an upgrade from the 18-55mm lens? Would the 15-88mm be sharper? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @kieran Larger focal length range, significantly better and faster autofocus and image stabilization which I understand the 4000D kit lens does not have.